# Add parentheses to a string with a given condition

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I wanted to add parentheses to the below strings under a condition. The numbers consist of two parts: "Id - subId", and I wanted to put parenthesis when there are multiple subId.

```
sample_string1 = "376-12~23, 28, 32, 35, 37,376-1"
sample_string2 = "391-1~8, 391-22~23"
sample_string3 = "391-10~21,  391-24, 27, 29"
```

These are my desirable outcome.

```
desire_string1 = "376-(12~23, 28, 32, 35, 37),376-1"
desire_string2 = "391-(1~8), 391-(22~23)"
desire_string3 = "391-(10~21),  391-(24, 27, 29)"
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty complicated Regex problem. I would honestly recommend that instead of using this solution, you instead separate out the variable that you want and make them tidy.

However, you asked this question, so here's a regex answer. I've used the `stringr` package because I find it easier and more readable than `grep`.

The regex breaks down like this:

`(?<=-)` - Positive lookbehind to find a - but don't capture it

`(\\d+[\\~\\,] ?[^\\-]*)+` - Capture a number of 1 or more digits followed by either a ~ or a , followed maybe a space followed by 0 or more characters that aren't a -. Capture a group that is 1 or more of these combinations of characters long.

`((?=, *\\d+-)|$)` - Find either a forward lookahead after the previous capture that contains a , some spaces and a number of 1 or more digits long, or capture the end of line character.

`replacement= "(\\1)"` - Replace the result that you captured with ( then the first group you captured then )

```
library(stringr)

sample_string1 = "376-12~23, 28, 32, 35, 37,376-1"
sample_string2 = "391-1~8, 391-22~23"
sample_string3 = "391-10~21,  391-24, 27, 29"
# (?!u)

ss1 <- str_replace_all(sample_string1,
                       "(?<=-)(\\d+[\\~\\,] ?[^\\-]*)+((?=, *\\d+-)|$)",
                       replacement= "(\\1)")
ss1
# "376-(12~23, 28, 32, 35, 37),376-1"

ss2 <- str_replace_all(sample_string2,
                       "(?<=-)(\\d+[\\~\\,] ?[^\\-]*)+((?=, *\\d+-)|$)",
                       replacement= "(\\1)")
ss2
# "391-(1~8), 391-(22~23)"

ss3 <- str_replace_all(sample_string3,
                       "(?<=-)(\\d+[\\~\\,] ?[^\\-]*)+((?=, *\\d+-)|$)",
                       replacement= "(\\1)")
ss3
# "391-(10~21),  391-(24, 27, 29)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex that produces the correct output is:

```
(?:(\d+-)((?:\d+~\d+|(?:,?\s*\d+){2,})+)(?=,\s*\d+-|\"))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QHDCMd/1/

- `(\d+-)` match the ID and the dash
- `\d+~\d+` match a subid range or ...
- `(?:,?\s*\d+){2,}` at least two subids
- `(?=,\s*\d+-|\")` positive look-ahead for next ID or closing quotes